# Search and replace in YML file + PHP

Tags: php, symfony, search, replace, yaml

Is it possible to search for a string in a yml file and replace it? This is a part of my yml file:

```
'PST Today': 'PST Today'
'PST Today Table': 'PST Today Table'
Hosttess: Hosttess
'Permit Total': 'Permit Total'
Visit: Visit
Conversation: Conversation
....
```

The first part on each rule before the `:` will always be the same, but now I want to look for the first part before the `:` and change the string behind the `:` . How can I do this?

Comment: Personally no experience with it, but you might try to look into yaml_parse() and/or file_get_contents()? Not sure, just trying to help. Will try if I have some time today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml` class. This is a part of Symfony Standard Edition. Do something like:

```
$dataArray = Yaml::parse($pathToYourYmlFile);
```

then you can do whatever you want (`array_filter` maybe?) to your `$dataArray` variable being regular array. Once you finish you can use:

```
$dataString = Yaml::dump($dataArray)
```

This will return string with yaml content which you can save back to your file, probably by `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0):

To match the value behind the ':' you can just do:

```
<?php
  $contents = file_get_contents('file.yml');
  preg_match_all('/^[^:]:\s+(.*)$/', $contents, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```